# Insert new random numbers inside an array *while* it is sorting

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Add new random numbers to the array being sorted every x seconds while the sorting function is running. For example x could be 1 second. The sorting of the array of 100k random numbers takes about 10 seconds. How would the sorting function update to take into consideration the new random numbers being inserted while the function is running? A web worker can be used to simulate concurrency if necessary.

https://repl.it/repls/OutstandingVioletPolyhedron

```
let a;
for (a=[],i=0;i<100000;++i) 
a[i]=i;

function shuffle(array) {
  let tmp, current, top = array.length;
  if(top) while(--top) {
    current = Math.floor(Math.random() * (top + 1));
    tmp = array[current];
    array[current] = array[top];
    array[top] = tmp;
  }
  return array;
}

a = shuffle(a)


const insertionSort = arr => {
  const len = arr.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    let el = arr[i];
    let j;

    for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && arr[j] > el; j--) {
      arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
    }
    arr[j + 1] = el;
  }
  console.log(arr)
  return arr;
};

const start = performance.now()
a = insertionSort(a)
const end = performance.now()
const time = (end - start) / 1000
console.log("time", time)
```

Comment: Can you add your code example directly to your post?

Comment: Not at all, JS is single threaded. JS will not execute any code while the sorting function *(or any function)* is running.

Comment: Can you please describe a use case? Also, sorting 100k elements with an efficient algorithm should be more or less instantaneous, how are you getting to 10 seconds?

Comment: @גלעדברקן See here https://repl.it/repls/OutstandingVioletPolyhedron. The use case is not relevant seeing that it's a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is single threaded. It can do one thing at a time. To make this work you'll have to rewrite the sorting function in non-possesive way so that it passes control back to other operations after some specific amount of time.

Comment: @marzelin  I can use a web worker to simulate concurrency.

Comment: @DanComan yes, you can use web worker and SharedArrayBuffer to actually do parallel computations, not just simulate it.